# SQLAlchemy's UnicodeText column is giving me a str on my MySQL table; shouldn't it be unicode?

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a simple table:

```
class MyTable(...):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = ...
    unicode_col = Column(UnicodeText())
```

Now I would like to get some data out of it:

```
assert type(session.query(MyTable).first().unicode_col) == unicode  # this fails
```

But that's not the case. It's giving me a `str` back.

According to [this page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Unicode), [this page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#unicode), and [this page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#coercing-encoded-strings-to-unicode), I believe it should be giving me `unicode` instead of `str`, given that I am passing `charset=utf8` in my connection URI.

The workaround I'm using is a simple type decorator, which works fine:

```
class CoercedUTF8UnicodeText(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = UnicodeText

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value.decode('UTF-8')
        return value

class MyTable(...):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = ...
    unicode_col = Column(CoercedUTF8UnicodeText())
```

But shouldn't sqlalchemy just give me `unicode` objects in the first place?

**Additional info**

If I use a sqlite database, I get `unicode`.

[Here's a self-contained runnable example.](https://gist.github.com/irskep/8345460)

I'm using Python 2.7.5, sqlalchemy 0.8.2, and MySQL-Python 1.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by upgrading to MySQL-Python 1.2.5 (from 1.2.3).

The problem was actually caused by a MySQL-Python bug that sqlalchemy doesn't yet account for. Filed and discussed here: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2906

Comment: This is what I actually did to fix my app.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the mysql-python driver? I suggest trying oursql instead:

```
pip install oursql
...
create_engine('mysql+oursql://...')
```

No need to even add charset=utf8 since it's the default for oursql.

Comment: This fixes the problem in the self-contained script above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `convert_unicode` flag when creating you engine, see [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api):

> if set to True, sets the default behavior of convert_unicode on the String type to True, regardless of a setting of False on an individual String type, thus causing all String -based columns to accommodate Python unicode objects. This flag is useful as an engine-wide setting when using a DBAPI that does not natively support Python unicode objects and raises an error when one is received (such as pyodbc with FreeTDS).

i.e.:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://filename', convert_unicode=True)
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution. Sometimes you do actually want bytestrings. Fixing the MySQL driver bug by upgrading is better than using a heavy-handed workaround.